# Como declarar que um campo tem o mesmo tipo de sua classe?

Tags: python, tipagem

Estou tentando adicionar tipagem no código em Python, e me deparei com um erro ao tentar anotar o tipo de uma propriedade que deve ter o mesmo tipo da classe em que ela é declarada:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Optional

T = TypeVar('T')

class Node(Generic[T]):
    value: T
    next: Optional[Node[T]]
                   ^ esse tipo não é reconhecido
```

Sei que o modo que eu anotei o tipo está correto, pois quando eu utilizo esse mesmo tipo em outra classe, eu não tenho erros:

```py
class LinkedList(Generic[T]):
    head: Optional[Node[T]]
    tail: Optional[Node[T]]
                   ^ aqui funciona normalmente
```

Porém essa sintaxe não é valida dentro da classe `Node`. Como posso fazer para tipar a propriedade `next` dentro de `Node`?

Comment: Se for Python >= 3.7, vc pode usar `from __future__ import annotations` (coloque no início do arquivo). Dizem que a partir do Python 3.10 esse código funcionará sem problemas (mas instalei a versão *pre-release* e ainda não funcionou, então vamos aguardar...)

Answer (score 3):

## Solução

Troque:

```
next: Optional[Node[T]]
```

Para:

```
next: Optional['Node[T]'] # agora como string
```

## Problema e motivação

O problema é que no ponto em que o `next` está a ser construído a classe `Node` ainda não existe. O próprio erro é indicativo disso:

> Unresolved reference 'Node'

Olhando para o [PEP 484 em Forward Declarations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-problem-of-forward-declarations) consegue ver o mesmo problema sendo detalhado:

> The current proposal is admittedly sub-optimal when type hints must contain forward references. Python requires all names to be defined by the time they are used

Traduzindo:

A proposta corrente é claramente não otima para tipos com referencias futuras. Python obriga a que todos os nomes estejam definidos no momento em que são utilizados.

Depois indicam como resolver:

> Our solution, which isn't particularly elegant, but gets the job done, is to allow using string literals in annotations

Traduzindo:

A nossa solução que não é particularmente elegante, mas que resolve o problema, passa por possibilitar a utilização de strings nas anotações.